# CSS adjacent disabled selector not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to update the background color of button if `input[type="file"]` is disabled but it is not working.

Any solution?

```css
.btn-file {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: auto;
}

.btn-file input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.btn-file input[type="file"]:disabled+.custom-file-upload {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-file .custom-file-upload {
  background-color: #6692b0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-file">
  <label for="FileUpload1" class="custom-file-upload">
      <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Logo
  </label>
  <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" class="" disabled="">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnkmmLbs/1/

Comment: @YakovL why did you voted down my question. It is a real issue that I was facing.

Comment: It wasn't me, no idea why somebody downvoted

Comment: If you'd like some advice regarding how to improve your question, I'd suggest to describe what exactly happens differently from what you expected: it's not quite clear from the snippet/fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with css `+` selector that says the next sibling, but the required element is previous not next. Switch order. `<input>` for `<label>`.

```
<div class="btn-file">
  <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" class="" disabled>
  <label for="FileUpload1" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Logo
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Even it doesn't work with any of the values that are mentioned in the above link. You can check them in the fiddle.

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisIqbal on it. cive me a second. I will update the answer later and let you know in comment

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisIqbal Check it out

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing Also, disabled="" is valid HTML5, albeit unusual.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for additional info and answer edit!

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisIqbal Happy to help.